# What should the exception screens for Money show?

Tags: discussion, top-7, design

Money should be nearing the end of its beta, so what should the exception screens be for Money?

The exception screens are

- 404 (Page not found)
- Error
- Captcha (the screen where you verify you are human).

Comment: Won't Jin, the SE designer, be the primary one dealing with these questions with community input?

Comment: @justkt certainly, but most sites have these questions answered for his perusal before he actually says "Time to design the site".  Nothing here is final, but it's a lot of useful input for Jin.

Comment: Related: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/184/logo-for-money

Answer (score 8):

What about a [cracked piggy bank](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&safe=active&biw=1387&bih=664&gbv=2&tbs=isch:1&sa=1&q=cracked+piggy+bank&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)?

Comment: A side question?  Are piggy banks worldwide?

Comment: @MrChrister Since it's been decided that the logo for the site is a piggy bank, and therefore it's international enough as a symbol, this could work for the error page.

Answer (score 8):

The captcha page could display a high-frequency trading system (i.e. a computer trading stocks):
[image]

The error or 404 page could display a bounced check:

[image]

I also like the cracked piggy bank idea.

Comment: I *really* like the robo trader idea for the captcha!

Comment: This is my current favorite.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the 404 or error page could show an ATM (cash machine) with a "not in service" or "out of order" message being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I think captcha page should display an ATM (since it's a robot/machine that produces money :), error page might display a falling stock chart, for 404 it'd be funny to draw a 404-dollar bill, but that might be too much work. Maybe broken piggy bank as Alex B suggests.

Answer (score 1):

A message explaining that the paperwork from the International Monetary Fund is hung up, but should be done shortly and the site will be back online then.